# Taking multiple inputs in python

Tags: python

I am writing a python program which no. of string user wants to enter as integer and then takes **N** number of strings from user and then separates strings based on their index and print even strings and odd string separated by space.

For Example:
Inputs from user: [image: 1]

and output:
[image: 2]

and had written this code in pycharm IDE:

```
    tc=input("Enter the no. of test cases you want: ")
    
    
    for j in range((int(tc))):
        n=list(map(int,input("Enter a string: ").split()))
        continue
        print(1)
    
    for i in range(len(n)):
        if i%2==0:
            print(n[i],end="")
    print(end=" ")
    for i in range(len(n)):
        if i%2!=0:
            print(n[i],end="")
```

but the problem I am facing is that when I input first string(hacker) and then it will ask for second input and when I input second string(sand) and press enter then it gives output of second string only(sn ad), however I want output as shown in the image above.

Comment: Please update your question with the *text* of the sample input and required output.

Answer (score 1):

You need to collect the inputs and then apply the same transformation to each one:

```py
tc = input("Enter the no. of test cases you want: ")

s = []
for j in range((int(tc))):
    s.append(input("Enter a string: "))

for n in s:
    for i in range(len(n)):
        if i % 2 == 0:
            print(n[i], end="")
    print(end=" ")
    for i in range(len(n)):
        if i % 2 != 0:
            print(n[i], end="")
    print()
```

Output:

```
hce akr
sn ad
```

Not quite as you specify.

Answer (score 0):

A simple answer for your question

```
n = int(input())
strings = [input() for _ in range(n)]
result = []
for string in strings:
    string_odd = string[::2]
    string_even = string[1::2]
    string = string_odd+' '+string_even
    result.append(string)
for res in result:
    print(res)
```

Output

```
hce akr
sn ad
```